# Join tables In SQL with SUM function

Tags: sql, inner-join, sql-server-2012

I'm working with SQL Server 2012 and have the following tables : `Ownership`, `Property`, `Person`

The table `Person` holds information about people such as first name, last name and this table has `PersonId` as primary key.

The table `Property` holds information about property such as property area, property description .. and this table has `PropertyId` as primary key

Because each person can have more than one property, and each ownership of a property can be more than one person, then we have a many-to-many relationship between `Person` and `Property`

So I created the table `Ownership` to break this relationship, so this table has `PersonId` and `PropertyId` as foreign keys, and the following columns : `PropertyId` as "Primary key", `StartDate`, `EndDate` and `OwnershipPercent`.

`Start Date` and `End Date` refer to the period in which the property is owned by someone, and the `OwnershipPercent` refers to the person's share of the property.

Now I would to write a query to return any property that is owned by more than one person by more than 100% in the same time

For example:

Property with `Id=1` belongs to person with #1 from 1-1-2010 to 1-1-2012 and his share of this property is 90%, and this property also belongs to another person with #2 from 1-1-2010 to 1-1-2012 and his share of this property is 80%.. as we see if we sum 90+80=170% at same time and this is wrong (because it would be less than 100% at same time)

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT A.PropertyId
FROM Ownership A INNER JOIN Ownership B
ON a.PersonId <> b.PersonId
AND A.PropertyId = B.PropertyId
AND A.StartDate <= B.EndDate
AND A.EndDate >= B.StartDate
group by A.PropertyId
Having (sum(A.OwnershipPercent)) <=100;
```

but if we have a property that belongs to 5 people, it makes (5×4)=20 sums and this is wrong

How to fix this ?

Comment: Instead of writing too much text you would have just showed the table schema ;) with some sample data...

Comment: I was not kidding. expected output and sample data attract the answer faster.

Answer (score 2):

I think the approach of a join on the ownership table is not quite right.  I see what you are trying to do, but the join is creating pairs of owners.  You want to think about sets of owners, instead.

My approach is to create a table with all the important dates for each property.  This would be the StartDate and EndDate in the OwnerShip table.  Then, let's look at the ownership percentages on these dates:

```
select os.PropertyId, thedate, SUM(os.OwnershipPercent)
from ((select PropertyId, StartDate as thedate
       from ownership
      )union
      (select PropertyId, EndDate
       from ownership
      )
     ) driver join
     OwnerShip os
     on driver.PropertyId = os.PropertyId and
        driver.thedate between os.StartDate and os.EndDate
group by os.PropertyId, thedate
having SUM(os.OwnershipPercent) <= 100  -- Do you really want > 100 here?
```

One key difference is that this query is aggregating on PropertyId and the date.  Tis makes sense because the amount of ownership can change over time.

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` will do right,

```
SELECT A.PropertyId
FROM Ownership A INNER JOIN Ownership B
ON a.PersonId <> b.PersonId
AND A.PropertyId = B.PropertyId
AND A.StartDate <= B.EndDate
AND A.EndDate >= B.StartDate
group by A.PropertyId
Having (sum(distinct A.OwnershipPercent)) <=100;
```

Comment: Your query return zero results... ;)

Comment: Probably that is what you want. Check your data.

Comment: Your query is incorrect.  Two different owners could have the same same ownership percent.  You would only be counting them once.  In fact, a property that had three owners all with 50% ownership would be include in this result set, even though the total ownership exceeds 100%.

Comment: yeah right. then sum() over (partition by personId) will do right?

Answer (score 0):

This request is probably necessary to you

```
SELECT PropertyID,
FROM dbo.Ownership
GROUP BY PropertyID, StartDate, EndDate
HAVING COUNT(PersonID) > 1 
  AND SUM(OwnershipPercent) <= 100 --in your question you want > 100
```

Comment: This would work if we assumed that coinciding ranges could only be totally identical. In reality, however, ranges may intersect or nest without being entirely identical.

Answer (score 0):

The following is similar to [@Gordon Linoff's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14124240/297408) in that it also "decomposes" the list of ranges into the list of start and end dates. However, it uses a different technique on the resulting list. It also assumes that only the beginning date is inclusive, while the ending date is not.

```
WITH unpivoted AS (
  SELECT
    PropertyId,
    EventDate,
    OwnershipPercent,
    PercentFactor = CASE EventDateType WHEN 'EndDate' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
  FROM Ownership
  UNPIVOT (
    EventDate FOR EventDateType IN (StartDate, EndDate)
  ) u
)
, summedup AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    PropertyId,
    EventDate,
    TotalPercent = SUM(OwnershipPercent * PercentFactor)
                   OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyId ORDER BY EventDate)
  FROM unpivoted
)
SELECT
  s.EventDate,
  s.TotalPercent,
  o.PropertyId,
  o.PersonId,
  o.StartDate,
  o.EndDate,
  o.OwnershipPercent
FROM summedup s
  INNER JOIN Ownership o
     ON s.PropertyId = o.PropertyId
    AND s.EventDate >= o.StartDate
    AND s.EventDate <  o.EndDate
WHERE TotalPercent > 100  -- changed from the original "<= 100"
                          -- based on the verbal description
;
```

To explain how this works, I'll assume the contents of `Ownership` to be the following:

```
PropertyId PersonId StartDate  EndDate    OwnershipPercent
---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------------
1          1        2010-01-01 2012-01-01 80
1          2        2011-01-01 2011-03-01 20
1          3        2011-02-01 2011-04-01 10
1          4        2011-05-01 2011-07-01 40
```

Now, you can see that at the first step, unpivoting, not merely every row of the original table is replaced with two rows, but also every percent value is marked as either an increment (`PercentFactor = 1`) or a decrement (`PercentFactor = -1`), depending on whether it comes along with the starting date or with the ending date. So, the `unpivoted` CTE evaluates to the following result set:

```
PropertyId EventDate  OwnershipPercent PercentFactor
---------- ---------- ---------------- -------------
1          2010-01-01 80               1
1          2011-01-01 20               1
1          2011-02-01 10               1
1          2011-03-01 20               -1
1          2011-04-01 10               -1
1          2011-05-01 40               1
1          2011-07-01 40               -1
1          2012-01-01 80               -1
```

At this point, the idea is basically to calculate running totals of `OwnershipPercent` at every `EventDate` for every `PropertyId`, taking into account whether the value is incremented or decremented. (You could, in fact, incorporate the sign into `OwnershipPercent` at the first stage instead of allocating a separate column of `PercentFactor`. I chose the latter as somewhat better illustrating the idea, but there should be no performance penalties if you preferred the former.) And this is what you get after calculating the running totals (which is what the second CTE, `summedup`, does):

```
PropertyId EventDate  TotalPercent
---------- ---------- ------------
1          2010-01-01 80
1          2011-01-01 100
1          2011-02-01 110
1          2011-03-01 90
1          2011-04-01 80
1          2011-05-01 120
1          2011-07-01 80
1          2012-01-01 0
```

Note, however, that this resulting set may contain duplicate rows. Particularly, it will if, for the same `PropertyId`, some ranges start or end simultaneously or some range ends exactly at the start date of another range. That's why you can see DISTINCT used at this stage.

Now that total percent values at key dates are known, those not exceeding 100 can just be filtered out and the rest joined back to `Ownership` for the access to the details of the ownerships contributing to the obtained totals. So, the main query gives you this as the final result:

```
EventDate  TotalPercent PropertyId PersonId StartDate  EndDate    OwnershipPercent
---------- ------------ ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------------
2011-02-01 110          1          1        2010-01-01 2012-01-01 80
2011-02-01 110          1          2        2011-01-01 2011-03-01 20
2011-02-01 110          1          3        2011-02-01 2011-04-01 10
2011-05-01 120          1          1        2010-01-01 2012-01-01 80
2011-05-01 120          1          4        2011-05-01 2011-07-01 40
```

You can also have a look at (as well as play with) this query [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9203d/1).